# GridDB connection with SQL workbench

Tags: passwords, database-connection, griddb, sql-workbench-j

I have been trying to make a connection of `GridDB` with `SQL Workbench`. I am getting an issue with the password. I have reset the password many times but getting the same error again and again. The password is correct as I had it noted during the installation and I can confirm it, but the prompt keep saying

> Sorry, try again.

The details for error can be seen here in the screeshot

[image: GridDB connection error]

I followed the [documentation](https://griddb.net/en/blog/connecting-to-griddb-via-jdbc-with-sqlworkbench-j/) to connect GridDB with SQL Workbench via JDBC.
In order to resolve the issue, I tried changing the password and then loggin back in but this also doesn't work in my case. Can someone please share their experience or thoughts on this part?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Workbench you should be using the database user and password. I think the default is admin/admin. If you want to add another user you can create one via SQL: https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v5_2/GridDB_SQL_Reference.html#create-user

The SUDO password is not the database password.